# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed also I tried to install gem openssl but can't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ssl-certificate

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

class myClass
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'

  def posts
    self.class.get('/users')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I got this error. And the simplest solution to this is as below.

1. Download cacert.pem file from this link http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. So, I have installed my Ruby in D drive inside Railsinstaller folder likewise,
   **"D:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\lib\ruby\2.3.0\rubygems\ssl_certs"** go to the directory where you have install ruby and got to this path **"Ruby2.3.3\lib\ruby\2.3.0\rubygems\ssl_certs**  inside this save the cacert.pem file, make sure it is .pem file.
3. Now, go to the environment.rb file in your rails application and save as below:
   ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = "/your/file/path/cacert.pem"

and DONE!